# How do I display content from API in text field in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Overview:**

I am trying to put some content in a text field for editing, but I am getting an error.

**The Problem:**

I would get an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'favorite_animal' of undefined`

**My Code:**

```
// import ...
// import ...

function getDataFromApi(id) {
  var url =
    "https://api.example.com/" + id;
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      return responseData;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
}

function myFunction(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromApi(props.id).then((response) => setData(response));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        <TextField>{data.details.favorite_animal}</TextField>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}

export default myFunction;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your first render will not yet have the data, so it's going to be `[]`. You need to check.  I would set the initial value to nothing, and then you can just do `if (!data) return null` before your current return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using fetch it takes some time to get this data so it is not ready on init yet, you have to add question mark like:

```
<TextField>{data.details?.favorite_animal}</TextField>
```

So what it does is that it firstly checks if `data.details` exists and if yes it takes `favorite_animal` value from it

But this will work if you are sure that you get `data.details.favorite_animal` from API. If code in `getDataFromApi` function is wrong and you don't get this data it will just not show anything